# how to install ncurses library in Android

Tags: c, installation, ncurses, replit

I tried to run a program but it was using `ncurses` library and that library was not installed in my system

I tried to run a program but it was using *ncurses* library and I was unable to run it I expected it will work properly.

Comment: See https://github.com/mirror/ncurses/blob/master/INSTALL

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.